# Add a line below subcategory

Tags: menu, submenu

I want to add a line below my subcategory link like in this [website](http://www.loreal-paris.fr/):

In the menu go to soin du visage and you can see black line like below in par type de soin.

How can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the classes in your own menu, but this is the `<CSS>` that is used in the site you refer to:

```
#mainNav .filters .title {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #070707;
}
```

You should try and add something similar to the `Cascading Styles Sheets` of your own store.

You can inspect the different classes by using the element inspector of your browser. I have added a screen shot of the site you refer to below. I used Google Chrome, just hold your mouse over the element that you wish to inspect and right click. In the menu that appears choose Inspect Element (at the bottom). Your screen will split and you can review a lot of details of the website.

[image]

This should help you identify the different classes and what style sheet to modify.

To learn a bit more about Google Chromes Element Inspector and `<CSS>` click [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements#css-styles).